# Set a Flutter beta channel only on VScode

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I use Android Studio and VScode for `flutter` programming.
Is there a way to set a `beta channel` only on `VScode`, While Android Studio does not change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **VS Code** we can not only set specific path to **Flutter SDK**, but enumerate all installed either by separate folders or root folder containing all SDKs, and then switch between them whenever we want.

You can specify the path in the `File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Flutter & Dart`

There is parameter called **Dart: Flutter Sdk Paths** and describer as:

> An array of strings that are either Flutter SDKs or folders that contains multiple Flutter SDKs in sub-folders. When set, the version number in the status bar will be clickable to quickly switch between SDKs.

If you prefer to edit `settings.json` file directly, add there something like:

```
  "dart.flutterSdkPaths": [
    "~/SDK/flutter-master",
    "~/SDK/flutter_linux_1.22.0-stable"
  ],
```

By clicking on SDK version bar (in the lower right corner), you can select one of the versions.
[image]

After you make a choice **flutter plugin** stores selected SDK path in another parameter `dart.flutterSdkPath` (very similar, only without `s` at end) in workspace specific **settings.json** file.